# Doubt in Transformation of Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I should know this but for some reason I have a complete mental block when it comes to transformation of Variables.  If we have:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = (a +by)x(1 + x^2) $$

And we wish to Transform by using:

$$ x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + e^{-q}}} \\
y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + e^{-p}}}
$$

Then how do we acheive this and how do we "re-write" $ \frac{dx}{dt} $ using the Transformed system?

In response to feedback below...

So what you are saying is...

$$ x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-q}}} \\
\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{1+e^{-q}} \\
\frac{1}{x^2} = 1 + e^{-q} \\
\frac{1}{x^2}-1 = e^{-q} \\
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}-1} = e^{q} \\
e^{q}=\frac{x^2}{1 - x^2} \\
q = \ln({\frac{x^2}{1-x^2})}
$$

So... $$ \frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{2 \dot{x}}{x-x^3}  \\
\frac{dq}{dx} = \frac{2}{x-x^3} \\
\frac{dx}{dt} = \dot{x}$$

Now, to rewrite the original $ \frac{dx}{dt} $ equation, I just substitute in my $ x $ and $ y $ into the RHS and $ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dq}{dt}\frac{dx}{dq} $ into the LHS.

$$ \frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{dq}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} \\
\frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{2}{x-x^3}  * (a - by)x(1-x^2) $$

Comment: As requested, original question reworked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

First of all $$x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-q}}}\implies \ln \left(\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right).$$

Now, use that $$\dfrac{dq}{dt}=\dfrac{dq}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}.$$

Comment: Thankyou, I have taken on board your comments and added to the original post.